# CakePHP AJAX-Call: An error occured: undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to get some sample ajax app running with cakephp. I started off reading this blogpost: http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/ which I tried to adapt do my architecture.

Now I am stuck here: 
When I change the selection of the first select-box, I get an error-alert: undefined.

When I trie to call the AJAX-URL directly in the browser, it actually returns the correct html-content that is supposed to be updated in the second select-box but I see there is an 500 Server-Error also being returned which sais it cannot load the recource http://localhost/favicon.ico. Is that the problem why the ajax-call sais "an error occured"? I don't know why this resource is even called and why it is looking in localhost/ and not the app-folder. Can anybody tell me what I need to do to get the ajax-sample running? This is the JS-Code for the ajax-call:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#countries').change(function() {

    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var targeturl = $(this).attr('rel') + '?id=' + selectedValue;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: targeturl,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            alert(targeturl);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            if (response.content) {
                alert("content");
                $('#provinces').html(response.content);
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText.message);
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

These are my controller-functions:

```
public $components = array('Session','RequestHandler');
...
public function chained_dropdowns() {
    $countries = $this->TestRun->find('list');
    $countryProvinces = array();
    foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
        $countryProvinces = $this->TestRun->TestStepRun->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('TestStepRun.test_run_id'=>$key)));
        break;
    }
    $this->set(compact('countries', 'countryProvinces'));
}
public function country_provinces_ajax() {
    //$this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');
    $id = $this->request->query('id');
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    //$this->viewClass = 'Tools.Ajax';

    //$this->loadModel('Data.TestStepRun');
    $countryProvinces = $this->TestRun->TestStepRun->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('TestStepRun.test_run_id'=>$id)));

    $this->set(compact('countryProvinces'));
}
}
```

And I added in my routes.php:

```
Router::parseExtensions();
Router::setExtensions(array('json'));
```

[Update]
I just changed the error-output-line to:

```
alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText);
```

Now, I get as error-message: "`An error occured: <option value="">...`"
This is the data from the json-view, which should be passed to the success-function. I just don't know, why it throws an error.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Debug it properly, using Firefox and Firebug extension for example it will give you the exact PHP error behind it in the response tab. Blindly coding doesnt help you at all here.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your replies! I am using CakePHP 2.6.1. I am not user whether I am doing now what you call proper debugging, but I am trying my best: FireBug sais in the Console/All:
 `Object { readyState=4, responseText="<option value="">pleaseS...="21502">21502</option>", status=200, more...}`
and in Console/Errors it sais nothing. It's just blank. Still the JavaScript jumps to the error-function. How can that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could it be, that it's rather a problem with your jQuery-request configuration?

Maybe try to add

`dataType:"html",`
in your $.ajax configuration.

to solve the issue. Normally CakePHP just outputs what you enter into your .ctp - file.

If you don't define json there, you will not get any object (regardless of what the console sais).